# Are these senteces correct?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I tried to correct them but I'm not sure about it. Is there a rule or a scheme to follow in order to correct them properly?

1.这幅画被我做了。 这幅画是我做的

2.我弟弟越来越高一点。 我弟弟越来越高

3.我只要喝茶,不要喝啤酒。 我只要喝茶,就喝啤酒

4.我们比学习的内容不太一样 。 我们跟学习的内容不太一样

5.我最好朋友比我考试得好。the position of 得 is always after the verb or not? 我最好朋友考试考得比我好

6.桌子上有一本想你像买一样的书,你去看一下吧。 桌子上有一本像想你买一样的书,你去看一下吧。

7.一年比一年学中文更难一点。 中文一年比一年学难一点

8.一分钟以后要下雨了,别忘带伞。 一分钟以后就要下雨了,别忘带伞。

9.老师说我现在不会去洗手间。 老师说我现在不用去洗手间。

10.我们都会骑自行车,连骑自行吃也妈妈会。 我们都会骑自行车,妈妈连骑自行吃也会。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Strong sentence is my revision for yours.

1.这幅画被我做了。 这幅画是我**画**的

2.我弟弟越来越高一点。 我弟弟越来越高

3.我只要喝茶,不要喝啤酒。 **我只想喝茶,不想喝啤酒**

4.我们比学习的内容不太一样 。 **我们学习的内容不太一样**

5.我最好朋友比我考试得好。the position of 得 is always after the verb or not? 我最好朋友考试考得比我好 **Ans:Yes**

6.桌子上有一本想你像买一样的书,你去看一下吧。 **桌子上有一本像你想买的一样书,你去看一下吧。**

7.一年比一年学中文更难一点。 **中文一年比一年难学**

8.一分钟以后要下雨了,别忘带伞。 一分钟以后就要下雨了,别忘带伞。same as**一分钟以后要下雨了,别忘了带伞。**

9.老师说我现在不会去洗手间。 **老师说我现在不能去洗手间。**

10.我们都会骑自行车,连骑自行吃也妈妈会。 **我们都会骑自行车,连妈妈也会骑自行车。**